# "mcopy error: No directory slots" when trying to make Makefile

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, operating-system, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When trying to execute "make" in WSL Ubuntu shell I receive the error stated in the title.
I have read about people having the same issue as I have 9 years ago. Apparently there was a bug in mtools 4.0.32 which caused the issue. Even though I have downgraded to 31 and also tried 43 it isn't working for me.

Here a snippet of my Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all floppy_image kernel bootloader clean always

#
# Floppy image
#
floppy_image: $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img

$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img: bootloader kernel
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img bs=512 count=2880
    mkfs.fat -F 12 -n "IZOS" $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img
    dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)/bootloader.bin of=$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img conv=notrunc
    mcopy -i $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img $(BUILD_DIR)/kernel.bin "::kernel.bin"
```

Here the make log:

```
mkdir -p build
nasm src/bootloader/boot.asm -f bin -o build/bootloader.bin
nasm src/kernel/main.asm -f bin -o build/kernel.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=build/main_floppy.img bs=512 count=2880
2880+0 records in
2880+0 records out
1474560 bytes (1.5 MB, 1.4 MiB) copied, 0.00281532 s, 524 MB/s
mkfs.fat -F 12 -n "IZOS" build/main_floppy.img
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
dd if=build/bootloader.bin of=build/main_floppy.img conv=notrunc
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 4.7067e-05 s, 10.9 MB/s
mcopy -i build/main_floppy.img build/kernel.bin "::kernel.bin"
No directory slots
make: *** [Makefile:17: build/main_floppy.img] Error 1
```

At this point I have no idea what is causing the issue.
Is it because of WSL?

Comment: `"::kernel.bin"` is supposed to be a directory, but I don't see where you create it.

Comment: @Philippe, it's unclear whether you mean `mcopy` requires that (it doesn't), or whether you recognize at a higher level what the OP is trying to accomplish, and *that* requires copying the file into a directory named `::kernel.bin` (plausible).

Comment: @JohnBollinger From "man mcopy" of Ubuntu/WSL : `mcopy [-bspanvmQT] [-D clash_option] sourcefile [ sourcefiles... ] targetdirectory`

Comment: Yes, @Philippe, that's *one* of the options.  But when there is only one source file, as in the OP's case, the target can be a regular file name instead of a directory name.  In every version of the manual page I've reviewed, that is the first-listed variant, right above the one you quoted.  Or you can see the same in [the main mtools docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html#mcopy).

Comment: I think that `mcopy` command should work, but you could also try using either `'::/kernel.bin'` or `'::\kernel.bin'` as the destination filename, to explicitly specify a file in the root directory of the filesystem.  Or perhaps just the root directory name, which you can express as `'::/'` or `'::\'`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have researched a bit and found out that ```'::'``` is the same as the cwd. ```'::/kernel.bin'```did I already try (it did not work). Knowing that it is the cwd, I replaced ```'::'``` with ```'.'``` also the cwd. Now it runs smooth like butter.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  There are two source files in the OP's case.

Comment: No, @Philippe, there is only one.  The `build/main_floppy.img` is not a source file.  It is the option-argument to [the `-i` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html#drive-letters).

Comment: @xunleqitrazer, `::` does not mean current working directory to the mtools.  It is a drive "letter" specifier for the `:` drive, which mcopy recognizes as the image file specified via the `-i` option. I hope you're right that the change worked for you, but my expectation would be that the result is to successfully copy the file from the `build/` directory to a destination on your system's disk, *not* into the image.  Note that if it went into a file literally named `.kernel.bin` then by default, that will not be shown by `ls` (use `ls -a`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I have to correct myself. I stated that I replaced ```'::kernel.bin'``` with ```'.kernel.bin'```. In my comment I have mistyped ```'./kernel.bin'``` as ```'.kernel.bin'```. A slight but quite challanging mistake to find.

Comment: @xunleqitrazer, either way, I don't expect that to have been put into the image.  But if in fact that did it then I'm glad your issue is resolved.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I think you are right. My make issue solved but in the ```'main_floppy.img'``` there is no drive. There is an image but no corresponding volume. I also tried switching to a VM but it did not work either. When executing: ```'mdir -i build/main_floppy.img'``` I get the following: ```' Volume in drive : has no label
 Volume Serial Number is 7856-3412
Directory for ::/

No files
                          1 464 832 bytes free'```. At this point I don't know whether it's worth it debugging...